# why does this not work in Rspec zombie.should_not be_valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

### app/models/zombie.rb

```
class Zombie < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name
    validates :name, presence: true
end
```

### spec/models/zombie_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Zombie do

    it "is invalid without a name" do
        zombie = Zombie.new
        zombie.should_not be_valid
    end
end
```

### errors

> Zombie
>        is invalid without a name (FAILED - 1)
>      Failures:
>
> ```
>  1) Zombie is invalid without a name
>     Failure/Error: zombie.should_not be_valid
>     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
>       Could not find table 'zombies'
>     # ./spec/models/zombie_spec.rb:5:in `new'
>     # ./spec/models/zombie_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
> ```
>
> Finished in 0.02912 seconds
>      7 examples, 1 failure
>
> Failed examples:
>
> rspec ./spec/models/zombie_spec.rb:4 # Zombie is invalid without a name
>
> Randomized with seed 12906

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Also, if :name is a column in the zombies database table you shouldn't need the attr_accessor line of the initialize method definition. The equivalent functionality will come as part of ActiveRecord.

Comment: Have you run migrations to create the zombies table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, I was not running migrations so running rake db:migrate fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You should not be defining an `initialize` method in ActiveRecord classes.

When I have the initialize method defined, this error comes up:

```
 Failure/Error: zombie = Zombie.new
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `delete' for nil:NilClass
```

Without it, it passes as you expect it.

So, change your model to the following and your specs will pass.

```
class Zombie < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

OR... if you feel you HAVE to, make sure you call `super` first

```
def initialize(options={})
  super
  self.name = options[:name]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

have you run rake db:test:load so the schema of the db is loaded on the testing db?

also your test is not right, you are testing that your model is invalid but you are not testing that your model is invalid BECAUSE it's name is not present, you should do something like

```
it "is invalid without a name" do
    zombie = Zombie.new
    zombie.should_not be_valid
    zombie.errors[:name].should_not be_blank
end
```

that way you really know that the name attribute has an error

Answer (score 0):

I am also working through this tutorial and had the same problem. I raked the migration and still didn't get the desired results. As arieljuod mentioned, running  `$ rake db:test:load` resolves the issue.